# Ubuntu Server can not connect to Internet; External network can not connect to Ubuntu server

Tags: networking, internet, dns

Okay, so heres the problem
After upgrading to 16.04, My Ubuntu server has lost all connections to the outside world. It is connected with ethernet to the modem, with the ports 21, 22, 80, 25565 The firewall on both the router and the Box are both disabled, and I have tried numerous DNS servers. I can reimage the server, but I am trying to avoid this. I have reset my Network Card, rebooted my machine, rebooted my router, and my modem.

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1c:23:e2:bb:ca  
          inet addr:10.0.0.124  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2601:45:8100:3944:21c:23ff:fee2:bbca/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::21c:23ff:fee2:bbca/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1592832 errors:0 dropped:182 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1607356 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:176241490 (176.2 MB)  TX bytes:381500041 (381.5 MB)
          Interrupt:16 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:48585 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:48585 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:15182251 (15.1 MB)  TX bytes:15182251 (15.1 MB)

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo net loopback


#The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.0.0.124
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.0.0.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of this terminal command: `cat /etc/network/interfaces` Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: Please also add the output of the command `ifconfig` (when run on the  16.04 server). Try `ping 127.0.0.1` on the 16.04 server to check that networking is up.  Then try `ping <ip address>` where <ip address> is the IP Address of your 16.04 server. This can be found in the output of `ifconfig`. It should read something like `inet addr:192.16.8.1.90` (your address will be different, but will very likely start with `192.168`). Try the second ping on the 16.04 server and also on another machine.

Comment: @NZD Done. Outside sources can connect now, I have removed DMZ mode and opened the ports 80 21 22 25565

Comment: @chili555 Look above

Comment: what are your remaining issues? Can you ping from the machine to other machines  and vice versa? Looking at the large number of RX and TX Bytes on eth0 and that there are no errors or packets dropped, it seems that everything works just fine.

Comment: Okay, so outside sources can access the server, but the server can't use commands like Ping, wget, apt, etc. Commands that require internet access @NZD

Comment: It is still able to ping computers within the LAN, but not outside of the LAN

Comment: Maybe your gateway is not set correctly.  Is `10.0.0.1` the address of your router? You also wrote that you only have ports 21, 22, 80 and 25565 open. Could you open up all ports and try again? Try `nmap <IP of gateway>`.

Comment: Okay, so it turned out that I had a broken network card. After replacing the card the server appears to be functioning normally.

Answer (score 1):

After replacing the Network Card the server began to function normally. It turns out there was a blown chip following a power surge.